# is it a clean way to create shipping options in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-helpers

I'm not very experienced with ROR, is it a clean way to create shipping options in a rails application ?

Just added this code in my orders_form :

```
<% if @order.subtotal >= 30 %>
  (free shipping)
  <%= f.radio_button(:shipping, "0.00", :checked => "checked", class: "hidden_field") %><br/>
<% else %>
  <p><strong>Shipping options :</strong></p>
  <%= f.label 'economy' %>
  <%= f.radio_button(:shipping, "3.00", :checked => "checked") %><br/>
  <%= f.label 'fast' %>
  <%= f.radio_button(:shipping, "5.00") %>
<% end %>
```

it seems too simple to me to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything's fine, but it's better to keep all this logic inside models, not in views. Something like this:

```
# order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  FREE_SHIPPING_THRESHOLD = 30.0
  ECONOMY_SHIPPING_PRICE = 3.0
  FAST_SHIPPING_PRICE = 5.0

  ...

  def eligible_for_free_shipping?
    subtotal >= FREE_SHIPPING_THRESHOLD
  end
end
```

Then `<% if @order.subtotal >= 30 %>` becomes `<% if @order.eligible_for_free_shipping? %>` and instead of hardcoding shipping prices in views you use `Order::ECONOMY_SHIPPING_PRICE` and `Order::FAST_SHIPPING_PRICE`.

With this approach you will have all order shipping settings in one place, so you don't need to go through many-many files when you want to change something.